# fetch 'no-store' does not reload data after page fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to get all the data new every time I go to a page. For this, I passed `'no-store'` as a parameter of the `fetch` method. But unfortunately, that doesn't work.

For example, if I create a new data record in MongoDB and then return to the main `page.tsx` page, this new data record should appear. But if it doesn't. I have to reload the page manually, and then I see it.

app/page.tsx:

```
 export const revalidate = 0;

 async function fetchData() {
 const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/products", {
   cache: "no-store",
 });

 const result = await res.json();

 return result.loadData.result;
}


 export default async function Home() {
 const products = await fetchData();
 ... 
 }
```

app/api/products/route.ts:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

import allProducts from "../../lib/allProducts";

export const revalidate = 0;

const fetchData = async () => {
 try {
 const fetching = await allProducts();

 return fetching;
 } catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
  }
};

export async function GET(request: Request) {
 const loadData = await fetchData();

 return NextResponse.json({ loadData }, { status: 200 });
}
```

app/lib/allProducts.tsx:

```
import Product from "../model/Product/page";
import mongoDBConnection from "./mongoDb";

export const revalidate = 0;

const init = async () => {
 await mongoDBConnection();
};

 export default async function allProducts() {
 try {
 await init();

const result = await Product.find({});

return { result };
 } catch (error) {
 console.log(error);
 }
}
```

Comment: Try removing that `revalidate` and see what it does.

Comment: Nothing. The same as if i add it

Comment: I use a third-party lib, MongoDB, for get the data in the router.ts inside /api/products.

Comment: Can you show `/api/products/route.ts`?

Comment: I have edit my orginal post

Comment: Is this SSG, SSR or client side page?

Comment: I use MongoDb so the mongoDBConnection stays in a SSR. Also all under the api folder like in my case /products/route.ts. All producst also is an ssr file. So the answer is, all files are SSR

Comment: And when you say "if I create a new data record in MongoDB and then return to the main page.tsx page, this new data record should appear" - do you mean it should appear automatically without a reload on the page? So that new data should be pushed to your page?